# nginx url rewrite without redirection

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure a reverse proxy in nginx.

```
http://apps.domain.example.com/abcadmin -> http://server1.exampl.com:8080/xyzadmin
```

So when I hit the URL `http://apps.domain.example.com/abcadmin` I should be able to view the content in `http://server1.exampl.com:8080/xyzadmin` without URL redirecting.

I have tried to configure the server as below. But I am not getting the exepcted result

```
upstream exe-al-server-up {
  server exe-ser-ab.rds-dev:8080;
}

server {
    server_name apps.domain.example.com;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location /abcadmin/ {
      rewrite ^/xyzadmin(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass      http://imp-al-ra-up/xyzadmin/;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the Rewrite rule.

```
upstream exe-al-server-up {
  server exe-ser-ab.rds-dev:8080;
}

server {
    server_name apps.domain.example.com;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location /abcadmin/ {
      rewrite ^/abcadmin(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass      http://imp-al-ra-up/xyzadmin/;
    }

  }
```